# Who was the person who came for another Jedi right before they were about to kill him?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

Who was the person who came for another Jedi right before they were about to kill him in *Revenge of the Sith*?

He appeared right after the scene where Aayla Secura gets killed, and the Jedi was told that he should leave right before the clones turned on him, and then the mystery person came in.

Comment: Which Jedi and which scene? I can think of a few that might fit....

Comment: A picture might be good, too.

Comment: The one right after Aayla Secura was Plo Koon, but that scene doesn’t fit the description you mention.

Comment: A young man with a blue lightsaber appears to jump in and kill all the clones, but i could have seen the scene wrong.

Comment: Could you provide a link to a video/screenshot so that it’s clear what you’re talking about?

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Zett_Jukassa?

Comment: Yeah that's the one

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### [Zett Jukassa](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Zett_Jukassa)

[image]

Zett Jukassa kills some clone troopers at the Jedi Temple during the execution of Order 66. [According to](http://www.starwars.com/video/bail-witnesses-order-66) the Databank:

> A young Padawan, Zett Jukassa fought heroically after clone troopers marched on the Jedi Temple to carry out Order 66. He fell in battle as a horrified Bail Organa looked on.

He can be seen fighting the clone troopers in the video [here.](http://www.starwars.com/video/bail-witnesses-order-66) The person who was told that he should leave was not a Jedi (else the clones would have tried to kill him), but Bail Organa.

<sub>He was played by Jett Lucas, son of George Lucas. The character’s name was based on the actor’s name.</sub>

Comment: Jett Lucas (worth mentioning)

Comment: So I had seen the scene wrong. Whoops